# Raspberry Pi jammed after few days of continuous work? size full?

Tags: python, linux

I made a project on raspberry pi 3+ and left it on over a weekend. After 4 days, when I came back, the program was not working. When I try to connect it with Remote Desktop, it was not working. I connected it over online server, the terminal was working but after 4,5 commands, it died too..... Than I restarted the raspberry pi than the project starts working fine... This happens because I checked the memory card's memory usage and it was full before restart 12.6 / 12.7 GB and was of the reduced / proposed size 5.00 / 12.7 GB. maybe its because of the log file? i dont know for sure!

This happens every time after few days. What would you suggest for this problem? Shall I reboot it every day via crontab command? I read at some places that this method will effect the working of rpi....
Any solution will be appreciated !!!!

Comment: `You need to find out what is using the disk space`.  Look at the `du` command which might help pinpointing large files.